# why cant i change the size of the time machine partition on my external drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, time-machine

i have 2 partitions on my external drive (macos high sierra 10.13.6).
1. time machine   1 TB
2. General storage 3 TB

i simply want to increase the size fo time machine partition to 1.5TB
and reduce the size of the other to 2.5 TB

I try to use the partition command in the disk utility app but the little slider does not appear and the apply button is greyed out when i type in a new value for the size

**here is the result of the diskutil command from terminal**

```
*Mikes-MBP:~ mikesmac$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            427.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                515.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS WD 4TB Silver Metal ... 3.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS WD 4TB Silver - Time... 1.0 TB     disk2s4*
```

Comment: Please add which Apple software you are using.

Comment: You possibly have an additional invisible partition between the two. Disk Utility won't show you these unfortunately. Use Terminal & type `diskutil list` then paste the result to your question [then select it & press Ctrl/k & it will format legibly in this page]

Comment: you know what... you sir might be a genious... I did notice a slight 'hashed area' , very thin pie slice on the graphical view of the partitions but i cant click on it. it shows between the 2 "known partitions" ... here is the info you asked for...

Comment: @Tetsujin . please note the info was too long to fit as a comment so I added it to my original post.  Thanks!

Comment: Odd. Something is in the way, but it's not showing what. Your 2 relevant partitions are s2 & s4… so where's s3? I'd be tempted to have a look at [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) & see what it makes of it [afaik there's a 14-day free trial]. I tend not to ever use Apple's own Disk Utility these days because it's not as transparent as it ought to be.

Comment: well I may have created another partition as a test when I was first setting up the disk and then deleted it. couldnt that have created an s3 ?    btw - is the s1 EFI partition a default part of the file system (because I didnt create it) ?

Comment: Yes, EFI is expected. The deleted partition is still odd that it doesn't show, but that may be the barrier. Paragon will get you round it, Disk Utility probably won't.